# Webpack with chunkFileName and source-maps

Tags: gulp, webpack, source-maps

A project I'm working on is using the code splitting facility of Webpack. I'm having trouble actually getting source maps to work with it. I've used source maps successfully on other projects that don't use code splitting and wonder if this is the issue. The output from `gulp task` indicates that source maps are indeed being created - they just don't appear to be available in Chrome.

This is the relevant section of my gulp file.

`files = globule.find(['./src/Components/*.*', '!./src/**/*-test.js']);
    gulp.src(files)
        .pipe(webpack({
            entry: "./src/components/settings.js",
            output: {
                filename: 'Settings.js',
                publicPath: "/admin/Content/Scripts/apps/",
                chunkFilename: "[name].js"
            },
            module: {
                loaders: [{
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                },{
                    test: /\.json$/,
                    loader: 'json-loader'
                },{
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 
                            'css-loader')
                }]
            },
          devtool: 'source-map',
            resolve: {
                extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
                alias: {
                'reactuifw': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' 
                ? process.env.REACT_UIFW + 'react-uifw.js' : 'react-uifw', 'react'         : __dirname + '/node_modules/react'
                }
            },
            externals: {
                jquery: '$'
            },
            cache: true,
            plugins: [new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css')]
        }))`

Any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've never gotten proper source maps working with devtool: 'source-map'; I think maybe it's shorthand for a particular config of the [SourceMapDevToolPlugin?](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#sourcemapdevtoolplugin) I use the plugin explicitly instead of using the 'devtool' option, with config as described in [this github issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/238) (ignore the WebStorm stuff). The issue has to do with the sourceRoot used in the maps. Maybe give that a shot and see if you get usable maps?